# How can I pass a value as class private property

Tags: php

is it possible for a class to accept a dynamic value and make it its private variable?

example:

```
class test{

private $var = $x;

private function fromUser($var){
//code here
}

}
```

i want `$x` to be dynamic like coming from a user input.

Comment: You can use `constructor` because your function is `private` so can't call outside to set value of `private property`

Comment: Could you more specific on 'user input'? Can it be a html form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure you can.  You can pass the value dynamically in a constructor or through a method?  Would something like work:

```
class Test {

    private $priv;

    function __construct($priv_value) {
        $this->priv = $priv_value;
    }       

    function get_priv() {    
        print $this->priv;
    }   

}

$test = new Test('testing');
$test->get_priv();
// testing
```

you could also define a `setter` method?

```
function set_your_private_variable($value_to_set) {
  $this->your_private_variable = $value_to_set;
}
```

Comment: is there a way we can make it a permanent private variable of the class after the user put the value? sort of like a one time input that will stay constant during a user session.